# Using JLabels as pseudo buttons

Tags: java, swing

Currently I am developing a small todo list manager and would like to use labels in place of buttons on the 'context' bar. If any one could provide me with information on how I could go about doing this I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to just use a JButton. It you use

```
button.setBorderPainted(false)
```

then it will look just like a label but you can still use an ActionListener.